# Inappropriate value for attribute "route": element 0: attributes

Tags: terraform, amazon-vpc

Inappropriate value for attribute "route": element 0: attributes "carrier_gateway_id", "cidr_block", "destination_prefix_list_id", "gateway_id",
│ "instance_id", "local_gateway_id", "nat_gateway_id", "network_interface_id", "transit_gateway_id", "vpc_endpoint_id", and "vpc_peering_connection_id" are
│ required.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet-1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "public-main-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public-subnet-2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.3.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "public-main-2"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "gw"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route = [
    {
      cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
      gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    Name = "rt"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is related to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761197/4624070

Answer (score 1):

Add all optional parameters to mitigate errors.
Here all empty blocks/parameters are optional but we have to provide all these to avoid errors.

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route = [
    {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
      carrier_gateway_id         = ""
      destination_prefix_list_id = ""
      egress_only_gateway_id     = ""
      instance_id                = ""
      ipv6_cidr_block            = ""
      local_gateway_id           = ""
      nat_gateway_id             = ""
      network_interface_id       = ""
      transit_gateway_id         = ""
      vpc_endpoint_id            = ""
      vpc_peering_connection_id  = ""
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    Name = "rt"
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).